# APACHE not starting on MAMP in Windows 10

Tags: apache, mamp

After installing MAMP on my windows 10 machine, I wanted to start the servers. I got the pop-up, 'APACHE' needs open port '80' which is already used by httpd. Please help.

Comment: Check what listen to this port

Answer (score -1):

The matter is resolved. The mistake was in the configuration.